# VBS or VBA for Multiple Excel Files?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Here is what I need to do:

I have around 1000 folders, within each of these folders is an excel file that I need to reformat (all the excel files are similarly formatted), I imagine the actual programming part is quite easy but that is besides the point. If I need to run a script on each of these excel files, should I use VBA or VBS?

As far as I understand, VBS can be run from the command line and doesn't require any Excel files to be open but VBA does require Excel to be open in order to run the script but that seems counter intuitive since I need to run a script on not just one workbook but a thousand.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Edit: I should say explicitly, I am trying to convert around 1000 CSV files to XLSX, I have tried python packages such as OpenPYXL and XLSXwriter but they are just terribly slow - it takes around 5 minutes per file.

Comment: I would use VBA in an excel workbook which can open and manipulate as many other workbooks as you like.  The integrated IDE will make things much easier.

Comment: @AlexK. Can I convert CSV files to XLSX in VBA?

Comment: Yes.  Easiest way is to start recording a macro, do it manually then look at the code it will generate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Python with the openpyxl package to implement your idea. The openpyxl package is [intuitively easy to use](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html), while Python's flexibility will allow you to get the job done in short term.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for answering. I have already tried openpyxl (also xlsxwriter and others), my main problem is that I have around 1000~ CSV files and I have tried converting them with openpyxl (and others), it just takes an incredibly long time for it convert from csv--->xlsx (around 5 minutes per file??) even when I use constant memory modes.

Comment: well, maybe an adaptation of this Go script will work for you https://github.com/tealeg/csv2xlsx